# How can I find all known ingredient strings in a block of text?

Tags: python, postgresql, parsing, elasticsearch, nlp

Given a string of ingredients:

```python
text = """Ingredients: organic cane sugar, whole-wheat flour,
       mono & diglycerides. Manufactured in a facility that uses nuts."""
```

How can I extract the ingredients from my postgres database, or find them in my elasticsearch index, without matching tokens like `Ingredients:` or `nuts`?

The expected output would be:

```python
ingredients = process(text)
# ['cane sugar', 'whole wheat flour', 'mono diglycerides']
```

Comment: Is "everything comma separated after the exact string 'ingredients:'" too naïve?

Comment: Why not make a list of all the ingredients and just look for them in the text? What the size of the corpus?

Comment: Depending on your input, this can be quite a complex task to do well, as there may be many syntaxes and variations (unless your input is always in the form `Ingredients: a, b, c & d. Notes.`, but this is usually not true for large bodies of real-world data).

I've done this several times and always ended up with some sort of parser. One Ruby-based implementation is [food-ingredient-parser-ruby](https://github.com/q-m/food-ingredient-parser-ruby), which uses [treetop](https://github.com/cjheath/treetop) for parsing. As it's not Python-based, I'm leaving this as a comment instead of an answer.

Answer (score 0):

This Python code gives me this output: `['organic cane sugar', 'whole-wheat flour', 'mono & diglycerides']`
It requires that the ingredients come after "Ingredients: " and that all ingredients are listed before a ".", as in your case.

```
import re
text = """Ingredients: organic cane sugar, whole-wheat flour,
   mono & diglycerides. Manufactured in a facility that uses nuts."""

# Search everything that comes after 'Ingredients: ' and before '.'
m = re.search('(?<=Ingredients: ).+?(?=\.)', text, re.DOTALL) # DOTALL: make . match newlines too
items = m.group(0).replace('\n', ' ').split(',') # Turn newlines into   spaces, make a list of items separated by ','
items = [ i.strip() for i in items ] # Remove leading whitespace in each item
print items
```